# Rails seed data nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling at making a seed data with nested arrays.
I have a VatClass model with the attributes name, valid_from, value.

```
vat_classes = [ ["empty", "1.1.2007", 0.0], ["reduced", "1.1.2007", 7.0], ["full", "1.1.2007", 19.0]]
vat_classes.each do |vat_class|
  vat_class.each do |inner_element|
    VatClass.where(name: inner_element[0]).first_or_create do |e| # pseudocode
      VatClass.create(name: inner_element[0], valid_from: inner_element[1], vat_value: inner_element[2])
    end
  end
end
```

If there aren't any previous records with the same name in the database then it should create one based on the vat_classes array. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second iterator is redundant:

```
vat_classes = [ 
  ["empty", "1.1.2007", 0.0],
  ["reduced", "1.1.2007", 7.0],
  ["full", "1.1.2007", 19.0]
]

vat_classes.each do |vat_class|
  VatClass.where(name: vat_class[0]).first_or_create do |e|
    # no create is needed anymore: it is already created
    e.update_attributes!(valid_from: vat_class[1], vat_value: vat_class[2])
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.